# MySQL Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search my database, I initially had it working with only one and condition but now with four, it will just refresh the page, removing field inputs.

I have tried using only a comma's but this appears to also not work.  I have been unable to find any information on Google about their being a limit but also no examples using four conditions.  Is there a correct or better way I could try?

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
   $address = trim($_POST['address']);
   $street = trim($_POST['street']);
   $city = trim($_POST['city']);
   $county = trim($_POST['county']);

   if($lname==""){
      $error[] = "Provide Last Name."; 
   }elseif($address=""){
       $error[] = "Provide House Number/Name.";
   }elseif($street==""){
      $error[] = "Provide Street.";
   }elseif($city==""){
       $error[] = "Provide City.";
   }elseif($county==""){
       $error[] = "Provide County.";
   }else{
       try{
           $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lname=lname AND address=address AND street=street AND city=city AND county=county");
           $stmt->execute(array("lname"=>$lname, "address"=>$address, "street"=>$street, "city"=>$city, "county"=>$county));
           $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

           if($userRow==''){
               $user->redirect('./results.php?new='.$lname.$street);
           }else{
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'good'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?good='.$lname.$street);
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'cautionextra'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?cautionextra='.$lname.$street);
               }
                if($userRow['rating'] == 'cautiondiscount'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?cautiondiscount='.$lname.$street);
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'cautionlate'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?cautionlate='.$lname.$street);
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'badnopay'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?badnopay='.$lname.$street);
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'badabusive'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?badabusive='.$lname.$street);
               }
           }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```

Executing `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lname=lname AND address=address AND street=street AND city=city AND county=county`in phpmyadmin returns all of the rows, great but when I `var_dump($userRow);`, it shows the results for a row different to the one of which I tried to search for.

Comment: No, all of these columns are required to get a result.  It's a very specific search

Comment: There's most probably capitalization mismatch. Have you tried running this query via mysql ?

Comment: There is none that I see, everything is lowercase excluding the conditions, yeah I get 0 errors.

Comment: You don't need: `":lname"` in execute(array()) just use index without colon in front: `"lname"`. Try copy-and-paste pure SQL into PHP My Admin or MySQL CLI to double check that you get any results. If you still receive 'no results' then try to drop one condition at the time and see when it starts to work again.

Comment: @DanielMinett - try removing all the conditions. Does that get results? If so, add the parameters back in, one by one, until it stops working.

Comment: Are you sure you have no results? var_dump($userRow); Have you tried running the query direct on the SQL database to ensure there is a matching record?

Comment: dump is NULL, I had not tried that, thank you I got a syntax error! #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':lname AND address=:address AND street=:street AND city=:city AND county=:county' at line 1

Comment: But if the same line worked with one AND why not 4?

Comment: @divix removing all of the colon's worked, drop it as an answer an I will accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: Question edited, removing colons didn't work, any thoughts?

Comment: I did have it `lname=:lname` to bind them but was told not to do this. Can you give a quick example of what you mean?

Comment: [Untested code at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8aSL22hX) - If you do an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some test data then it would be easy to test.

Comment: Thanks for the pastebin, it works 50% but it is finding no results and loading the no results page.

Comment: @RyanVincent I got it working using your solution, if you supply as an answer I shall accept.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that using an `equality test` for the `search` columns makes it difficult to get a match with any row because:

- the entered values must match exactly to the column in the table row.
- all the search columns must be entered. If they are empty then they will never match any row.

The approach with search fields is:

- try to `approximately match` the `input value` with `column value` by using `like` instead of `=` as the comparison operator.
- make an `empty input value` match *any column value*. i.e. ignore the test

The supplied code will generate code: `column like %` for empty input or will wrap the input value in wildcards: `column like %input value%`

[Untested source at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/8aSL22hX)

Untested code:

```
<?php // completely untested code...
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
                           FROM clients
                           WHERE  lname   like :lname
                            AND   address like :address
                            AND   street  like :street
                            AND   city    like :city
                            AND   county  like :county");

    $stmt->execute(array("lname"  => empty($lname) ? '%' : '%'. $lname .'%',
                         "address" => empty($address) ? '%' : '%'. $address .'%',
                         "street"  => empty($street) ? '%' : '%'. $street .'%',
                         "city"    => empty($city) ? '%' : '%'. $city .'%',
                         "county"  => empty($county) ? '%' : '%'. $county .'%'));

    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need: `":lname"` in `execute(array(...))` just use index without colon in front: `"lname"`.

**Full line:**

```
$stmt->execute(array("lname"=>$lname, "address"=>$address, "street"=>$street, "city"=>$city, "county"=>$county));
```

Comment: After cache clear, this doe snot work, on any PC it just refreshes the search page with the fields empty.  any idea?  Updated code in question.